# Marshmallow permission popup hides fragment UI beneath

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

My app asks for permissions in Parent activity while fragment is shown to user already

when app asks for permission the background becomes complete white I want to show permission dialog on top of fragment but not covering full screen

Any ideas?

adding code below

```
int finePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (finePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), PERMISSION_CODE);

        }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Screenshots? Code?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar added code as well as screenshot

Comment: `when app asks for permission the background becomes complete white I want to show permission dialog on top of fragment but not covering full screen` - Can you elaborate a bit, its kinda confusing

Comment: sure @MohammedAtif basically permission dialog hides fragment as you can see in screenshot

Comment: So you dont want permission dialog to hide the fragment or you want to show something particular behind the permission dialog?

Comment: @MohammedAtif I want this dialog not to hide other content white looks odd

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve, but Android is too particular about their System level permission should look like. So unfortunately you can not do anything with the appearance. for more details - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request

Answer (score -3):

add this line to your dialog

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: thats system dialog permission not from my app :)